# Algorithm for finding set of all parents recursively

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose I have a directed graph $G=\{V,E\}$, with edges $E$ and vertices $V$. I am interested in subsets of vertices $A\subset V$ with the following properties:

$\forall x\in A, Pa(x)\in A$

$\nexists B\subset V$ s.t. $\forall x\in B, Pa(x)\in B$ and $A\subset B$

That is, if a vertex is in this set, then its parents are also in this set, and there are no other sets with this property that are supersets of this set. Is there a term for such a subset of vertices? Is there an efficient algorithm for finding *all* such subsets for a given graph?

Comment: I suspect there is a graph theory term for what I'm trying to compute, but I am not aware of it. It's not the same as strongly connected components, although any strongly connected component should be a subset of the full set to be unioned.

Comment: It seems to me offhand that some simple variation of the [union-find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-find_algorithm) should do what you want, but I haven't thought about it very carefully.

Comment: So much of math or computer science is like magic: in all of these, you need to know the name of something in order to control it or make use of it. I find it very frustrating when I can't search for something because I don't know its name or how to properly describe it.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I post things on math.SE :)

Answer (score 1):

To find the smallest such set containing a fixed vertex $v\in V$, simply perform a depth- or breadth-first search starting from $v$, only searching backward along arcs (that is, if you are at $v$, and there is an arc $w\mapsto v$, then you add $w$ to the list).

Comment: Yes, that will find a set for one vertex. What about all?

Comment: Of course, one could brute force it. But there is probably something more elegant.

Comment: What do you mean by 'all'?  I mean, at some point you're just taking the full vertex set, yes?  Or, say, the largest $W\subseteq V$ such that there are no arcs $W^C\mapsto W$?

Comment: Ah, I realize I was too general in what I was describing. I *also* want $A$ to have the property that there is no other set $B$ that contains all the parents of elements such that $A \subset B$. So in that case, you would first have to find the minimal elements of the graph, then apply this algorithm at those elements.